# Different Object Identities on Different IDEs in Python

Tags: python, ide

I know that the title is a bit strange, but I was trying some things on my own and by the way, I am a beginner who is currently learning Python.

My problem is, I've tried the same thing on different IDEs and they gave me different results. `Jupyter` shows me that two different variable names attached to the integer 750 have two different identities (I've made the assignments separately).

But when I try this in PyCharm, two different variable names attached to the integer 750 are giving the same identity. What causes this difference between two IDEs? What am I missing? Which one should I accept?

I've tried this experiment with strings.

for example '`abc`', and there is no problem with strings

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since even integers are objects in python and object creation is expensive, some integers (from -5 to 256) are created once at the beginning of the session and reused from that pool whenever you want to reuse them. But for numbers outside that range I'm surprised that you get the same id. I wonder why.

Comment: Interestingly, if I assign 750 to two names separately in a script and run it with IDLE, it says they have the same id. Same if I execute the code `a = 750; b = 750; id(a), id(b)` in the shell. But if I make the assignments in their own lines in the shell, they'll have different ids.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Python `id` function just returns the memory address of that specific object (in Python everything is an object). So there is no guarantee about the value that will be returned from this function. If you rerun PyCharm or restart your Jupyter instance you will get different results almost everytime.

Comment: Yup.  Nothing really “logical” or classifiable about that `id`.  It’s not exactly a RAM address pointer but close enough and it is essentially random for the average dev’s POV.  The only time matches/not matches really matter are when comparing ids *within the same Python process*.